# QSizePolicy issue in PySide6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside6

I'm trying to centre the buttons in a QToolBar using two dummy spacer widgets, but I'm not able to set the size policy for some reason. Not sure what I'm doing wrong as the error says I'm passing a tuple, which should be accepted (last line from output), but apparently is not. Works ok without the size policy lines, but obviously I don't get the desired outcome.

Example:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from __feature__ import snake_case, true_property


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_ui()

    def set_ui(self):
        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.window_title = "Main Window"
        central = QWidget()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(central)
        tool_bar = MainToolBar()
        self.add_tool_bar(Qt.ToolBarArea.TopToolBarArea, tool_bar)
        self.central_widget = central


class MainToolBar(QToolBar):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        group = QActionGroup(self)
        
        home = QAction("Home", group)
        page2 = QAction("Page 2", group)
        page3 = QAction("Page 3", group)

        left_spacer = QWidget()
        left_spacer.size_policy = (QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        right_spacer = QWidget()
        right_spacer.size_policy = (QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.add_widget(left_spacer)
        for action in group.actions():
            action.checkable = True
            self.add_action(action)
        self.add_widget(right_spacer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Vlad/Documents/test.py", line 46, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "/Users/Vlad/Documents/test.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.set_ui()
  File "/Users/Vlad/Documents/test.py", line 18, in set_ui
    tool_bar = MainToolBar()
  File "/Users/Vlad/Documents/test.py", line 34, in __init__
    left_spacer.size_policy = (QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
TypeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.size_policy.fset' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.size_policy.fset(tuple)
Supported signatures:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.size_policy.fset(PySide6.QtWidgets.QSizePolicy)
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.size_policy.fset(PySide6.QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy, PySide6.QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy)
```

Comment: This relies on the `true_property` problem that cannot properly handle overloads (and that's another reason for which people doesn't really like both `true_property` and `snake_case`). Try changing to `left_spacer.size_policy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! I don't really mind if it's not snake_case, but I do like the true_property.

Comment: Note that there are other reports about similar issues when using those features (especially if used together). Interestingly enough, fixing them sometimes results in making things much more complex, and it seems that even the author of those features feels a bit of regret in having added them. Honestly, I frankly *hate* the `snake_case` (it's unnecessary, inconsistent, and confusing, also considering documentation), and while I might understand `true_property` (especially for consistency with python's `@property`), I sincerely hope that they will drop them sooner or later.

Comment: Good to know. Maybe you can make a report on https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/PYSIDE and ask to add that support for the overload. But that would add an even further "workaround" to a system that wasn't really necessary in my opinion. The equal assignment is not exactly the same as a `setSomeProperty()` function: even considering some level of sanitization, if I do `a = b` I would expect some level of `a == b`. Some @property specific behavior is considered and acceptable, but not for a "meta" property system that should always provide a consistent pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I might actually consider dropping it then if it actually causes that many issues. I'd imagine it will be annoying to have to rewrite the code if they drop the feature.

Comment: Yeah, that would be, and that's one of the many reasons for which I normally discourage them. They're not consistent with the library (especially the snake case) and if, for any (good) reason, they decide to drop their support you will have to fix thousands of occurrences, with the possibility of creating silent bugs that may be very difficult to track. Note that while the `@Property` decorator doesn't directly allow the Qt property behavior of base classes (with the parentheses for the getter), there are workarounds: https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2020-October/043348.html